# bash script - how to find and handle the last item read from a while loop using a case statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm using a `while` loop to read in a list of items in a file. Within the while loop, 
i'm also using a `case` statement to handle particular conditions/columns. One condition that I cannot figure out is 
how to handle the *last* item on the list.

For example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
FILE="myoutputfile.out";
while IFS='' read -r column; do
  case column in
    visitor_id)
       echo "isnull($column|| '[|]' ||";;
       updated)
       echo "isnull($column::text || '[|]' ||";;
             *)
       echo "isnull($column::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||";;
  esac
done <"$FILE"
```

Let's say list contents are:

```
visitor_id
updated
visitor_list_1
visitor_list_2
visitor_list_3
visitor_list_4
visitor_list_5
```

I need to do something different with "**visitor_list_5**". Note, the list will be different each time except for the first 2 items which 
I have a case for, but I need to handle the last one with something like so:

```
   last_column)
   echo "isnull(visitor_list_5::text,'[null!]')) as md5sum"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `wc` to get the line count. Something like the following:

```
file="myoutputfile.out";
linecount=$(wc -l $file)
counter=1
while IFS='' read -r column; do
  case column in
    visitor_id)
       echo "isnull($column|| '[|]' ||";;
       updated)
       echo "isnull($column::text || '[|]' ||";;
             *)
       echo "isnull($column::text,'[null!]') || '[|]' ||";;
  esac
  if [ "$counter" -eq "$linecount" ]; then
      #you found the last line
  fi
  ((counter++))
done <"$file"
```

Also, consider avoiding using all upper-case variable names. Your system's variables are all upper case like `PATH` and you risk a collision.